# Searching a non repetitive in Vi

Tags: regular-expression, search

I'm quite new to Linux as well as to vi so I have several questions.

Assume the text is as below:

```
Hi one and one.
Hi one.
```

1. Is there anyway to search the first line where the word `one` exist twice in the same line and do not search for the second line where `one` only exist for once?
2. Is there anyway to search for the second line where the word `one` only exist for once and ignore the first line where it exist twice?
3. Can I search and only display which line does the word falls in without opening the file by vi initially? (just search by typing command in the terminal, not the one in the vi as some vi files may have millions of lines and want to avoid the time opening it)

Comment: @aarontan, to help others to find question and reuse answer we prefer question with a focus. The third part of your question could deserve à question by its own. Welcome to Vim :-)

Comment: Voting to close as these should be several questions. Let me make it clear that I do consider 3 to be on topic and related to Vim as shown by Vivian's answer. Feel free to create new questions to follow up. Also [take the tour](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tour), see [how to ask](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and read Vim's built in `:help`.

Comment: @aarontan, Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further. Otherwise maybe could you accept a solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first I would do:

- `gg` go to the start of the buffer
- `/\<one\>.*\<one\>` search a line with two times `one`

More information with: `:help /\<`

That you could also rewrite:

- `/\v<one>.*<one>`

For the second I would use the following regular expression:

- `\(\<one\>.*\)\@<!\<one\>\(.*\<one\>\)\@!`

More information with: `:help /\@<!` and `:help /\@!`

That you can also rewrite:

- `\v(<one>.*)@<!<one>(.*<one>)@!`

For the third I would use the `:grep` command that populate the quickfix window with the file/line that match the regular expression.

More information with: `:help grep`